# How to show this function is integrable

Tags: integration, measure-theory

How to show the function $F_a: \mathbb R^d\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $F_a(x) = \frac{1}{1+|x|^a}$ is integrable if and only if $a>d$? I guess I should show that $F_a$ is not bounded if $a\leq d$. When $a\leq d$, the discrete version of the integral looks like (**How to show exactly?**) $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i}$ which has no limit. **Is this the right way to solve this question?**

Answer (score 3):

This method uses spherical coordinates, which you might not find elementary enough.

In spherical coordinates, we may write
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \frac{1}{1 + |x|^a} \, dx = \int_{S^{d-1}} \int_0^\infty \frac{r^{d-1}}{1 + r^a} \, dr \, d\sigma = \sigma(S^{d-1}) \int_0^\infty \frac{r^{d-1}}{1 + r^a} \, dr,$$
where $\sigma$ is the area measure on the $d-1$-dimensional sphere $S^{d-1}$.

It remains to calculate for which $a$ the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{r^{d-1}}{1 + r^a} \, dr$ is finite. Outside the origin $\frac{1}{1 + r^a}$ behaves like $r^{-a}$, so the relevant condition here is that $d-1-a < -1$, or $a > d$.